# Resource strings as title for a tabLayout

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

So I have the following problem:
I want to use a string array as the title for a TabLayout.

In this case I am using a ViewPagerAdapter for the Layout and now I want to save the title of the tabs in a string array.

To provide a translation of these title I am using 2 resource strings but I can't use them because the string array can only use strings and the resource strings are ints (perfect sentence).

> Incompatible types.
>
> Required: **java.lang.String**
>
> Found: **int**

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    String[] tabTitleArray = {
        R.string.dice, R.string.presets
    };

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {

        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The Error is here:

```
   String[] tabTitleArray = {R.string.dice, R.string.presets};
```

Also: I can't use `getResource().getString();`

Comment: Why not convert those values into Strings instead of resources?

Comment: If you are not able to use getResources(), then do onething pass your string array in your adapter with FragmentManager and declare there string array using getResources()

Comment: final Stringlabels = getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.String.labels);

Answer (score 2):

A staightforward solution would be to provide the ViewPagerAdapter with the Context in order to access resources, like:

```
public ViewPagerAdapter (FragmentManager manager, Context context) {

    super(manager);
    this.mContext = context;
}
```

and then

```
mContext.getResource().getString(....)
```

Comment: @2Simpel just to comply with SO rules, please accept one of the answers published or post yourself the solution and accept it

Answer (score 0):

Use string array instead :

```
<string-array name="labels">
   <item>my URL1</item>
   <item>my URL2</item>
</string-array>
```

and to use it :

```
 final String[] labels = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.labels);
```

Comment: Works but it cannot resolve the method getResources()

Comment: use getContext() or getActivity() if using it in fragment  to access getResources().getStringArray(R.array.labels). Or pass the context of the activity in adapter\

Comment: Initialize the string array in activity/fragment and pass it in the constructor of your adaptor like Lino has suggested

Comment: I did it :) Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you accept the answer if this was your solution ? I dnt know so just guessing